# Sort javascript array by numbers and letters

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

I want to sort this javascript array:

```
 [103,3,4,6,8,"8L",67,1,11,19,68,86,107,"9L"];
```

sort it by numbers and letters, so the result will look like this:

```
 [1,3,4,6,8,"8L","9L",11,19,67,68,86,103,107];
```

When I try to use `sort()`, it doesn't work:

```
 [1,3,4,6,8,68,103,"8L",11,19,67,86,107,"9L"]; // 8L and 9L are in the wrong place
```

```js
// correct wanted order
var correct = [1,3,4,6,8,"8L","9L",11,19,67,68,86,103,107];
document.body.innerHTML += '<b>correct wanted order:</b> <pre>' + JSON.stringify(correct) + '</pre>';

// array to order
var unordered = [103,3,4,6,8,"8L",67,1,11,19,68,86,107,"9L"];
document.body.innerHTML += '<b>array to order:</b> <pre>' + JSON.stringify(unordered) + '</pre>';
    
unordered = unordered.map(item => {
  return item;
});

var ordered = unordered.sort(function(a, b) {
     return a - b;
});

document.body.innerHTML += '<b>order attempt:</b> <pre>' + JSON.stringify(ordered) + '</pre>';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: what have you tried? Do you encounter any issue?

Comment: Where would "8M" appear in the sorted list

Comment: @sylvanaar, right after "8L" (sort by alphebeticly)

Comment: @amphetamachine Sort() indeed should be used, but the answer is how?

Comment: @D.Seah I have updated my code snippet to show you what I've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily using array [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) & [`localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method by passing the `{numeric: true}` option like:

```js
var unordered = [103,3,4,6,8,"8L",67,1,11,19,68,86,107,"9L"];
var correct = unordered.sort((a,b) => 
  a.toString().localeCompare(b.toString(), undefined, {numeric: true}))
console.log( correct )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not a PHP programmer. You can try to post a new question regarding that with a PHP tag.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you'll want to start by treating everything in your sort function like a string. Then split the numbers from the rest of the string and test them separately. Something like this:

```js
const ordered = unordered.sort(function(a, b) {
  // Break apart the assumed strings (Numbers then everything else)
  const [, aNumber, aString] = `${a}`.match(/(\d*)(.*)/);
  const [, bNumber, bString] = `${b}`.match(/(\d*)(.*)/);

  // Test numbers
  if(Number(aNumber) < Number(bNumber)) return -1;
  if(Number(aNumber) > Number(bNumber)) return 1;

  // Test letters if there is a tie
  return aString < bString ? -1 : 1;
});
```