# Sort posts by Custom Field of numbers and letters (combined)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sorting

I want to sort my posts by a custom field called "custom_order".

The "custom_order" field will have value that can have number / letters / both, for example:

`[103,3,4,6,8,"8L",67,1,11,19,68,86,107,"9L"];`

Example: post 1 `custom_order` field is -> `103`;

Example: post 2 `custom_order` field is -> `3`;

Example: post 3 `custom_order` field is -> `4`;

... posts 4 5...

Example: post 6 `custom_order` field is -> `8L`;

And so on...

---

I want WordPress to sort the posts by numbers & letters.

So this would be the **good order**:

`[1,3,4,6,8,"8L","9L",11,19,67,68,86,103,107];` <-- Notice this combined alphabetical & numeral sort (6,8,8L,9L)

---

I'm using this function in `functions.php` and it indeed sorts the posts, but in the **wrong order**:

`[1,3,4,6,8,68,103,"8L",11,19,67,86,107,"9L"]` <-- Notice that 68 comes before 11, 9L comes after 107 and more problems.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function ($q) {
    if (
        !is_admin() // Target only front end queries
        && $q->is_main_query() // Target the main query only
        && ($q->is_search() || $q->is_post_type_archive('data-base'))
    ) {
        $q->set('meta_key', 'custom_order');
        $q->set('order',    'DESC');
        $q->set('orderby',  'meta_value');
    }
});
```

[I found a solution that sorts the array in JavaScript in the correct way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61683362/sort-javascript-array-by-numbers-and-letters/61683612?noredirect=1#answer-61683612), but I can't manage to make it work in WordPress.

Any idea of an approach to solving this?

Comment: Order by field()?

Comment: @Strawberry What do you mean?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field

Comment: Cool! How to implement this in WordPress query though?

Answer (score 0):

Not gunna touch the code, but Strawberry's suggestion of ordering the field modifies the sql like this:

```
select * 
from your_table 
order by field(custom_order, "1","3","4","6","8","68","103","8L","11","19","67","86","107","9L")
;
```

I've assumed that custom_order is stored as a varchar or other string type hence the quotes around the integers.

Comment: Thanks, @Lnr. The thing is the field items are dynamically changed per post - I can't predict the values of the custom field.